# Django: bulk update from a list of dicts without constructing the whole query set

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a list which contains dicts. Something like:

```
[{'id': 0, 'price': 20}, {'id': 1, 'price': 10}] # a few thousands of elements
```

how can I update corresponding models without constructing the whole QuerySet?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "constructing the whole QuerySet".

Comment: What model do you want to update?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem let's call it `Match`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can use [**`.bulk_update(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update):

```
data = [{'id': 0, 'price': 20}, {'id': 1, 'price': 10}]

Match.objects.bulk_update([Match(**kv) for kv in data], ['price'])
```

We here thus construct `Match` objects that we then pass to the `bulk_update` to construct an update query.

Comment: `Match(**kv)` is it expensive operation when we create thousands of them? Probably not, but...

Comment: @kharandziuk: it will not make any query, it will create a `Match` object, so it is equivalent to `Match(id=0, price=20)`, it is not "free", but likely it will not be the largest bottleneck.

Comment: What is this `Match`, a python module or django thing ?
Where can I import it from??
Thanks

Comment: @WaqarAli: that is the model for which we want to do a bulk create. So if you want to create `Profile` records in bulk, you replace `Match` with `Profile`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ignore the dumb me. Thanks alot.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how this approach identify the index/key when doing the update?

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike this is great! Can you please what "Match(**kv) for kv in data" is doing exactly, particularly this bit Match(**kv) ?

Comment: @squidg: it "unpacks" a dictioanry, so if the dictionary is `{'id': 0, 'price': 20}`, it calls `Match(id=0, price=20)`.